# Safest way to return string from bash function (<4.3) when function contains other echos

Tags: bash, function, shell

I want to print some logging style messages in my function, but also need to return a string value at the end of the function.

I came across namespaces but unfortunately I'm not working a recent enough version of bash.

For example:

```
doThing() {
   echo "stuff"
   echo "things"
   echo "usefulstring"
}

result=$( doThing )

[[ $result = "usefulstring" ]] && echo "Worked" || echo "Failed. :("
```

I would really rather avoid globals, and from what I've read I should avoid eval. 
So what other options are there?

Also -  I would like to see the logging echos on stdout, but not the return value. Is it possible to use redirection within the function to achive this?

Comment: @anubhava the test was purely for demonstration, I need to store "usefulstring" in result somehow. Possibly through variable expansion?

Comment: @JordanMackie: You mean to say you want to `echo` multiple strings, but return only the last

Comment: @Inian that's it exactly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming if you are OK with a minimal disk I/O, you could open a file descriptor to write to a file and then later parse it once the function is complete.

In this example, fd `3` will serve our purpose

```
doThing() {
   echo "stuff"
   echo "things"

   exec 3<> /tmp/foo
   echo "usefulstring" >&3
   exec 3>&-
}
```

and now parse this file using `read` for a single variable or `mapfile` if you are passing multiple words to the array. This way, the variable holds the string values even if they contain spaces between.

```
doThing
read -r str < /tmp/foo
```

The result would be available in `str` which you can quote it in conditionals. If your file system keeps `/tmp` or `/var` busy, you could use `mktemp` to create a file on your local directory to use for the fd.

This also satisfies your last requirement - I would like to see the logging echos on stdout, but not the return value.

Comment: Love it! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an array and get the last element:

```
doThing() {
   echo "stuff"
   echo "things"
   echo "usefulstring"
}

# This creates an array
result=($( doThing ))
echo ${result[@]}    # Just for debugging

# This get the index of the last element
end=$(( ${#result[*]} - 1 ))
result=${result[$end]}

echo $result    # Just for debugging

[[ $result = "usefulstring" ]] && echo "Worked" || echo "Failed. :("
```

Gives:

```
stuff things usefulstring
usefulstring
Worked
```

Comment: This will break if `usefulstring` is `useful string`

Answer (score 1):

In general, logging-type output from a program (or shell function) that's distinct from its primary output data should be sent to standard error rather than standard output, something like this:

```
doThing() {
   echo "stuff" >&2    # Logging output goes to stderr
   echo "things"  >&2
   echo "usefulstring"
}
```

...then `result=$( doThing )` will print "stuff" and "things" to stderr, and set `result` to "usefulstring". If you want the logging output to wind up going to the script's standard output, you can redirect it back like this:

```
result=$( doThing ) 2>&1
```